# How to pass vector elements as arguments to variadic template function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

So, let's say I have this code:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
auto sum(T1 a, T2 b) ->decltype(a + b) {
    return a + b;
}
template <class T1, class T2, class... T3>
auto sum(T1 a, T2 b, T3... tail) ->decltype(a + sum(b, tail...)) {
    return a + sum(b, tail...);
}
```

I would like to call function `sum` in a way I pass a vector:

```
vector<double> numbers = { 1, 2, 6, 5 };
```

that should be used as a list of arguments for function `sum`. How can I do that? Calling function `sum` should return 14 in this case.

Comment: Variadic functions are resolved at compile time, and vectors have a runtime determined size. Perhaps you should specialize for vector arguments, instead.

Comment: You can also use std::array, whose size is known at compile time.

Comment: @Claudiu just an FYI: your link points here. ;-)

Comment: @Brian I'm trying to avoid fixed length array. For example, I need to input N values from `std::cin` and I don't know how many of them are going to be there. But at the end I would need to pass them all to a `sum` function.

Comment: @Tracer you can't pass a different number of arguments into a variadic function depending on runtime information, unless you shoehorn it in with a series of conditional statements.

Comment: Why do you want to use variadic templates at all?

Comment: @MikeMB I'm just trying to pass non-fixed length array to variadic function.

Comment: Yes, but why as a list of arguments, instead of just passing the vector?

Comment: I can not talk for Tracer, but consider that he may not be in a position to modify the variadic function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::vector` is a run-time beast. That is, it allocates its buffer on the heap and generally any manipulation is allowed during run-time. On the other hand variadic template "pealing" is done during compile time. Consequently, a `std::vector` and variadic templates are somewhat "disjoint". Thus, it's not possible to do what you want with a vector.

If you want to sum the elements of a vector this can be done in run-time using `std::accumulate`:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

As Brian mentioned in the comments you could use a `std::array` for compile time computation in combination with `constexpr` functions. An example of how you could do this is displayed below:

```
namespace detail {
template <class T1, class T2>
constexpr auto sum_(T1 a, T2 b) {
    return a + b;
}
template <class T1, class T2, class... T3>
constexpr auto sum_(T1 a, T2 b, T3... tail) {
    return a + sum_(b, tail...);
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr T sum_impl(std::array<T, N> const &src, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  return sum_(src[Is]...);
}

}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T sum(std::array<T, N> const &arr) {
  return detail::sum_impl(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76a5a3d0b1ef04f1)

In the above example I marked your `sum` functions `constexpr`. You can also figure out how you can use `std::make_index_sequence` to feed the elements of your array as arguments to your variadic `sum` function.