# Create dynamically null terminated parameters for C binding

Tags: c++, gstreamer, variadic

For my project I am binding a C++ method to a C function.
This function is from gstreamer and is variadic in this form :

```
GstElement *gst_element_link_many(GstElement *el1, GstElement* el2 ,[...], nullptr);
```

Let's say I want to pass a vector to my bindings, what would be your approach ? Ideally I would have this result

```
void linkElements(std::vector<GstElement*>& elements) {
    [...]
    gst_element_link_many(elementList... , nullptr);
}
```

I am thinking of parameter packs but I am unsure of how to implement those.

Thanks !

Edit: I can't modify the gstreamer function so I can't pass a pointer. Gstreamer as a gst_element_link(GstElement* el1, GstElement *el2); function but it behaves differently because it links elements 2 by 2 and thus computes capabilities of each pair independently.

Comment: Are your vectors limited in their length?

Comment: They are not. In practice I can put from 5 to 10 arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing all elements of an array to a function with variable parameters (...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275163/passing-all-elements-of-an-array-to-a-function-with-variable-parameters)

Comment: C++ has a lot more options than plain C, I am sure there must be a better solution.

Comment: @EmmanuelRuaud: Have a look at this post: [How to pass vector elements as arguments to variadic template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34233797/how-to-pass-vector-elements-as-arguments-to-variadic-template-function)

Comment: From what I understand, the solution proposed is to iterate and reduce it to a function between two arguments, that works for a sum but not for gst_element_link_many because it needs the whole number of arguments in one go to compute correctly.

Comment: There is a better duplicate to look at: [Passing parameters dynamically to variadic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1721655/4955498). It mentions  [avcall library](https://www.haible.de/bruno/documentation/ffcall/avcall/avcall.html)  that does that at runtime

Answer (score 1):

Parameter packs are a compile-time construct, while a vector is a runtime construct. This makes parameter packs irrelevant for this question. There are several solutions, short of redesigning the interface of the C function.

**The first option** is given in
M Oehm's answer to [Passing all elements of an array to a function with variable parameters (…)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26281065/4955498) mentions the technique of one big switch:

```
void linkElements(std::vector<GstElement*>& elements) {
    switch (elements.size()) {
      case 0: return gst_element_link_many(nullptr);
      case 1: return gst_element_link_many(elements[0], nullptr);
      case 2: return gst_element_link_many(elements[0], elements[1], nullptr);
      case 3: return gst_element_link_many(elements[0], elements[1], elements[2], nullptr);
      case 4: return gst_element_link_many(elements[0], elements[1], elements[2], elements[3], nullptr);
      ... and so on for how long one wants to support
      default:
         throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(elements.size()) + " elements can't be passed (too many elements"));
}
```

The disadvantage is that this method defines the maximal number of parameters at compile time.

**The second option** is to automate the `switch` statement. It uses recursion, so it may be less efficient than the other options, but it is very easy to extend to more parameters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <unsigned size, class Func, class Type, std::size_t... I>
void call_n(Func func, const std::vector<Type> & vec, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    func(vec[I]...);
}
template <unsigned size, class Func, class Type>
auto call_n(Func func, const std::vector<Type> & vec)
{
    return call_n<size>(func, vec, std::make_index_sequence<size>());
}

template <unsigned min, unsigned max, class Func, class Type>
void call_max_n(Func func, std::vector<Type> & elements)
{
    if (elements.size() == min) {
        call_n<min>(func, elements);
        return;
    }
    if constexpr(min < max)
        call_max_n<min+1, max>(func, elements);
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("Too many elements");
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<const char*> elements{"%s %s %s", "hello", "nice", "world"};
    call_max_n<1, 4>(std::printf, elements);
}
```

You can try it out on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pYQdO6dZsaAlp7Ix). From my tests, gcc is able to create a flat function. Maybe fore more complicated examples it will actually use recursion but, regardless or that, the complexity is O(n) just as if it was called without any recursion.

(EDIT: replaced the [O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jSATo8G3bVdR4uYk) with the linear algorithm shown above).

**The third option** is given in Matt Joiner's [answer to "Passing parameters dynamically to variadic functions"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1721684/4955498) mentions a C library that can be used to convert a vector into variadic templates:

> [FFCALL](http://www.haible.de/bruno/packages-ffcall-README.html) is a library which provides wrappers for passing parameters
>   dynamically to variadic functions. The group of functions you're
>   interested in is [avcall](http://www.haible.de/bruno/documentation/ffcall/avcall/avcall.html).

The above links are outdated, and [this link](https://github.com/rurban/ffcall) seems to be more up to date.

From the way I understand the documentation, your code should look like:

```
#include <avcall.h>
void linkElements(std::vector<GstElement*> & elements) {
    av_alist alist;
    av_start_void(alist, &gst_element_link_many);
    for (auto ptr: elements) {
       av_ptr(alist, GstElement*, ptr);
    }
    av_ptr(alist, GstElement*, nullptr);
    av_call(alist);
}
```

I am not sure how portable this is. It seems to work on Linux Intel machines (both 32 and 64 bits). Maybe it can also work on Windows. If it does not work on your system, then I think it is not too difficult to port it to your system.

And **the last option** is to use assembly. It is possible to put the data from the array into the correct registers and/or the stack. This is not very complicated, and can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) for the Intel architecture.

Unfortunately, all the flexible solutions are not purely C++ and require some add on (either from a library, or from an assembly code).

**EDIT**: I have added one of the solutions to [github](https://github.com/michael-veksler/applicable), and I intend to all all of the above solutions.

Comment: @EmmanuelRuaud I have added another option, which automates the first `switch` option to any number of parameters. This one does use parameter packs.

Comment: Nice one, I will have to compile on ARM at some point so it's certainly the one I will go for ultimately.

Comment: @EmmanuelRuaud I had another edit - made the second option run in linear time